# Code reuse with template non-type arguments

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a function, say

```
int square(int i) {
   return i * i;
}
```

And a template int version of it:

```
template<int i>
int square() {
  return i * i;
}
```

Can I somehow share the implementation code, or do I need to maintain two separate functions?

Comment: You can probably just implement a `constexpr` version and forget the template version. If is already in use, you can implement it in-terms of the `constexpr` instead.

Comment: The obvious answer would be to have the template call `square(i);` - But since you are asking, it's obvious that won't do. So please explain the actual issue more thoroughly.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It might actually be that simple in my case :D I wanted to get some optimizations related to some arithmetic with constants. I will check if the optimizations kick in.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it would not be the same. While `i * i` is a constant expression , `square()` is a non-constexpr function which can not be evaluated at compile time. Implementing a `constexpr` version would make it evaluable at compile time.

Comment: What I discovered regarding this is that I didn't need the template function, I got proper optimizations as long as the non-template function was inlined. That's not very reliable, though. I really liked the constexpr approach, but in my actual case I couldn't use it since I'm using memcpy to bitcast in my function, which isn't allowed in a constexpr context.

Comment: C++20 has introduced `std::bit_cast` which is constexpr. This may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Mechap , I was aware of that, but I'm on C++17 for this codebase